# No response from postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up a small postgresql server on my raspberry pi.  So far, I've:

- Installed postgres onto my pi
- Set a static IP adress for my pi
- edited  `/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` so that `listen_addresses = '*'`
- edited `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` to include

  `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5`

Running `pg_isready` on my pi gives me

```
root@pibox:~# pg_isready
/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

However, running the following results in no response

```
root@pibox:~# pg_isready -d <db_name> -h<static_ip> -p 5432 -U postgres
<pi's IP>:5432 - no response
```

Additionally, I'm not able to connect from my laptop

```
psql --host=<static IP> --port=5432  --dbname <db name> --username=postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "<the pi's IP>", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
```

What are some of the next steps I can take so that I can connect to my postgres server from my laptop and execute queries against the databases?

EDIT:

My laptop is running macOS 12.4.  I'm connecting to my pi via ssh over my home network.  The pi is running a copy of DietPi.  Here is some more relevant info

```
root@pibox:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Running the following commands yeilds these outputs

```
root@pibox:~# pg_isready
/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections

root@pibox:~# pg_isready -d postgres -h <Pi IP> -p 5432 -U postgres
<Pi IP>:5432 - no response

root@pibox:~# pg_isready -d postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres
127.0.0.1:5432 - no response


root@pibox:~# pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
13  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
```

Comment: 1) On Pi try; `pg_isready -d <db_name> -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` or `pg_isready -d <db_name> -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres`. 2) For remote connection are you sure there is not a firewall in the mix? 3) Did you restart/reload server after making conf changes?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) Running that command with the db_name results in `localhost:5432 - no response`.  2) I'm not sure about firewalls.  Could you point me to a relevant thread?  3) Yes, I restarted the server after conf changes with `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: 1) To be clear you ran `pg_isready` on the Pi, correct? Did you try the `127.0.0.1` version? 2) Is there more then one version of Postgres installed on the Pi? 3) As to firewall that is going to need more info: a) What OS is laptop running? b) How are you reaching the Pi from the laptop, local network or remote one? c) What OS and version are you running on Pi?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, I ran the `pg_isready` command with the hostname you provided. It resulted in `no response`.  I don't think there is more than 1 version of postgres intsalled, this is a fresh installation of the pi OS.  Will add more context to my post for your other questions

Comment: 1) I asked if you ran it with the localhost IP, 127.0.0.1? 2) On the Pi what does `pg_lsclusters` return?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver See [this](https://i.imgur.com/2DiCopm.png) image for the output of `pg_lsclusters` as well as the result of `pg_isready` using localhost. I've run it with localhost and with its own static IP

Comment: Don't post images, copy and paste the information as text into your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ok, the output of `pg_isready -d gymbro_dev -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres` is `no-response`.  The output of the same command using `-h <pi IP>` is `no response`.  The output of `pg_lsclusters` is `13  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've added all output to my question for future reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250539/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-demetri-pananos).

Comment: I'd say you either didn't restart PostgreSQL after you changed `listen_addresses`, or there is a firewall in the way. At any rate, this is a network problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Not a network issue.  The OS i'm using is DietPi.  Its a problem with their "optimized" version of postgres.  I'll write an answer to my own question tomorrow.